# Data not being submited to SQL Database using MySQLi and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Here's my original post: [Why is data I upload getting renamed, and corresponding data added to different rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640839/why-is-data-i-upload-getting-renamed-and-corresponding-data-added-to-different)

I was able to edit the code a little bit (using the solution I was given) so that the image that was submitted to the server via the insert form had the same name as the file I uploaded.

> **Example:** I upload turtle.jpg into the form and click Insert. The file
>   "turtle.jpg" would be written into the database where it is located at
>   on the server (images/turtle.jpg). And then a success message would
>   pop up.

But everytime I sent data, the image and the other data would be inserted into the database on 2 SEPERATE rows. I have no idea why. I also tried modifying my code so that it used mysqli instead of mysql and nothing works anymore.  No errors but no data is sent into the database.

Here's my new php code:

```html
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('$host', '$user', '$pass', '$databasename');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

 $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
 $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
 $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
 $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
 $imagename= $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'];
        $target_path = "images/".$imagename;
        
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO charts ( charts_URL ) VALUES ('".$target_path."')");
        or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        
} else {

        echo "<p> It is not working </p>";

    }


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$date = $_POST['date'];
$retrace = $_POST['retrace'];
$start_of_swing_trade = $_POST['start_of_swing_trade'];
$end_of_swing_trade = $_POST['end_of_swing_trade'];
$bull_flag = $_POST['bull_flag'];
$bear_flag = $_POST['bear_flag'];
$ema_crossover = $_POST['ema_crossover'];
$trading_instrument = $_POST['trading_instrument'];
if($date !=''||$trading_instrument !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$sql = "INSERT into charts (charts_date, charts_retrace, charts_start_of_swing_trade, charts_end_of_swing_trade, charts_bullflag, charts_bearflag, charts_ema_crossover, charts_trading_instrument) VALUES ('$date', '$retrace', '$start_of_swing_trade', '$end_of_swing_trade', '$bull_flag', '$bear_flag', '$ema_crossover', '$trading_instrument')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection with Server
```

The only time that data is inserted into the database is when I use the old mysql_query code.  But my database says it supports the mysqli extension.

```
Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.35-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: cpses_msLpFymSYl@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web Server
cpsrvd 11.48.1.2
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

phpmyadmin
Version information: 4.0.10.7, latest stable version: 4.4.2
```

**Here's a snippet of the my current PHP code (which is basically the code you posted in your solution) with the `GetImageExtension` function added:**

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $databasename);
    // Check connection can be established
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
        function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
    {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }

    $target_path = '';
    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
        $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
        $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
        $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
        $imagename= $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'];
        $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $retrace = $_POST['retrace'];
    $start_of_swing_trade = $_POST['start_of_swing_trade'];
    $end_of_swing_trade = $_POST['end_of_swing_trade'];
    $bull_flag = $_POST['bull_flag'];
    $bear_flag = $_POST['bear_flag'];
    $ema_crossover = $_POST['ema_crossover'];
    $trading_instrument = $_POST['trading_instrument'];
```

Comment: You made two separate queries there. It either you combine all bothe queries or obtain `insert_id` of the first query and use `update` for the second query.

Comment: `INSERT INTO charts ( charts_URL )...` and `INSERT into charts (charts_date, charts_retrace,...` will cause 2 rows.

Comment: You have two `INSERT` statements.  Why is it surprising that you're inserting two rows?

Comment: @David - How would I convert my original code to mysqli then because the mysqli code I made didn't work.  Only my mysql.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from your `mysqli_connect()` params.

Comment: like this? `$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $databasename);`

Comment: @frz3993 - look at above comment, thanks.

Comment: yes @Thomas. See if it works

Comment: @frz3993 - didn't work. blank screen after I click Insert and no data inserted into the database.  I also tried combining the two `Insert` statements.

Comment: You changed `mysqli_connect` to `new mysqli`. Of course it won't work. The procedural and object oriented style have different ways to be implemented.

Comment: @frz3993 - which way am I doing the code then? procedural or object-oriented?  and if I am doing it one way, what should the correct code be?  it's really confusing and I've been stuck on it for hours.

Comment: when you use `new mysqli` you are creating an object. But further down in your code you use procedural `mysqli_connect_error()`, `mysqli_query`... etc. Furthermore you used uninitialized variable `$mysqli`. It doesn't matter which way you want to use, but use prepared statement.

Comment: I'll put an answer which is object oriented style. I'm really refraining myself from rewriting codes, but I'll do it this time. Read the codes carefully, you might need to change some variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to check the variable names and adjust it to your liking. Use prepared statement to prevent sql injection.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection can be established
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $target_path = '';
    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
        $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
        $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
        $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
        $imagename= $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'];
        $target_path = "images/".$imagename;
    }

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $retrace = $_POST['retrace'];
    $start_of_swing_trade = $_POST['start_of_swing_trade'];
    $end_of_swing_trade = $_POST['end_of_swing_trade'];
    $bull_flag = $_POST['bull_flag'];
    $bear_flag = $_POST['bear_flag'];
    $ema_crossover = $_POST['ema_crossover'];
    $trading_instrument = $_POST['trading_instrument'];

    if($date !=''||$trading_instrument !=''){

        $sql = "INSERT into charts (charts_URL, charts_date, charts_retrace, charts_start_of_swing_trade, charts_end_of_swing_trade, charts_bullflag, charts_bearflag, charts_ema_crossover, charts_trading_instrument) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        // s = string, i = integer, d = double, b = blob
        //preparing statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        if(!$stmt){ exit("prepare failed");}
        //binding param
        $bind = $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',$target_path, $date, $retrace, $start_of_swing_trade, $end_of_swing_trade, $bull_flag, $bear_flag, $ema_crossover, $trading_instrument);
        if(!$bind){ exit("bind failed");}
        //will return 0 if fail
        if($stmt->execute() != 0){

            echo "New record created successfully";
        }else{ echo "Failed to insert new record";}

    }
//close connection
$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error; Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetImageExtension()

Comment: ok so I fixed the error with the original `function GetImageExtension($imagetype)` code I had in my previous post.  but now no data is being sent to the database and no failure/success messages displaying.

Comment: Modified answer. Added some codes to see where it failed.

Comment: still nothing. no errors or any messages displayng. just a blank screen after I click Insert.  by the way, I edited my question, adding a snippet of the PHP code I have with the new GetImageExtension function.

Comment: error log shows:

[20-Apr-2015 07:59:57 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/mscott62/public_html/chart-submission/insert_backend.php on line 72

The end of my file shows: `//close connection
$conn->close();
}
?>`  line 72 is the last line in the file.

Comment: `//close connection` and `$conn->close(); } ?>` suppose to be in different lines. LOL

Comment: They ARE on different lines.  The markdown formatting doesn't allow me to post code the way I have it in the file.  So I'm still not sure what is causing the syntax error and why nothing is displaying after I click Insert.

Comment: unexpected line of files usually caused by missing brackets or enclosure. If you use a decent IDE, you can easily detect that. Missing brackets anywhere in the file can cause that. Even semi-colon can cause it

Comment: Even missing only one bracket can cause that

Comment: Used notepad++ to find the missing bracket.

This line towards the beginning of the file: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` was missing a closure so I put the end bracked at the end right before `?>`

Now I get an error on the page after clicking Insert:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/mscott62/public_html/chart-submission/insert_backend.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined variable: bind in /home/mscott62/public_html/chart-submission/insert_backend.php on line 61
bind failed

Comment: Make sure you have 9 `?` in the query values. 9 `s` at the `bind_param` with nine variables

Comment: finally got it to work.  data was inserted into the database. but still error along with success message: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/mscott62/public_html/chart-submission/insert_backend.php on line 60

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('siiiiiiii',$target_path, $date, $retrace, $start_of_swing_trade, $end_of_swing_trade, $bull_flag, $bear_flag, $ema_crossover, $trading_instrument);`

i changed `$bind` to `$stmt` and even I change the `s` to anything else, it still gives error.  For the VALUES, I put my database variables so that the data would be inserted. `VALUES ('".$target_path."', '$date', '$retrace', '$start_of_swing_trade', '$end_of_swing_trade', '$bull_flag', '$bear_flag', '$ema_crossover', '$trading_instrument')";`

Comment: If you put the variable directly into the query you can drop the bindparam. But this will defeat the purpose of prepared statement.

Comment: wait...what? drop the bindparam.....but defeats the purpose of prepared statement......I'm confused.  soooo.....what should I do? and if I put question marks into the VALUES code, how will the data I put in the form be inserted in the database?

Comment: The `?` serve as the placeholder. When you bind param you are binding the variables to the `?`. In short PHP mysqli will replace the placeholder with the value for you

Comment: it worked! no more errors. but now I am curious. for the images, I tested 2 different images and the names of the images get written into the database as file paths (eg: images/image.png) but the actual image is not uploaded into the image directory.  any idea?

Comment: fixed it. put this line right above the query code: `if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {`

Now I just gotta figure out what to do with the user controlled codes which makes my code vulnerable.

Comment: Sorry, was not at home. When you use prepared statement and bind param you are already secured from first order sql injection.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your help man! And hey.....it never hurts to help people....taking a few moments out of your time to rewrite code if it means helping someone is always a good thing, specially if your ability to get the code right is on a high level :)

Answer (score 1):

> But everytime I sent data, the image and the other data would be inserted into the database on 2 SEPERATE rows. I have no idea why.

Why would you expect it to land in the same row? You perform two different insert queries. If you do want to use two queries, the second one would have to be an update of the previously inserted row. But obviously, that's not the preferred way, just use one query.

Combine your `if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"]))` and `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and then use something like this, where you insert the URL at the same time into the same row as all the other values:

```
INSERT into charts (charts_URL, charts_date, charts_retrace, charts_start_of_swing_trade, charts_end_of_swing_trade, charts_bullflag, charts_bearflag, charts_ema_crossover, charts_trading_instrument) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

**Security**

Please note that your code is **extremely unsecure**. `$imagename` is user controlled, so your first query is open to SQL injection. The values in your second query are obviously user controlled, that too is vulnerable. SQL injection can take place in all sorts of queries, including on inserts. It makes it possibly to leak data, DOS you, and possibly execute code or change data. **Use prepared statements to protect against SQL injection**. It's simple to use and results in nice code, there is no reason not to use it.

Note also that `$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"]` is user controlled as well and independent of the actual file type or extension. **You should not trust it** when deciding on the extension of the image on your server (if you do, an attacker could eg upload a PHP script).

Comment: yea, thanks for the tip but I have no idea how to do prepared statements in mysqli.  I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem I am having.  I can do the code on my own but it will take me several attempts and will usually end up with me asking for help.

Comment: [mysqli prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It's really simple, and security is quite important. As for your problem: I think my post contains everything you need to solve it, you should be able to do it with some trying around (it's easier for you to do it, since we would have to set up the database, etc to test it; and you will definitely learn more when you do it yourself). Like I said, just combine your two if blocks and your two inserts into one, and that's it. Once it works, migrate to prepared statements.

Comment: for sure I can do it and I can learn it faster and retain more info better if  I do it myself but it also helps me go faster when I have another brain giving me tips when I stumble on weird code.,  me and frz up there already combined the two inserts into one.  Now trying to figure out what's causing the errors.